# Finding a suitable direct sum decomposition of a decomposable kG-module

Tags: modules, representation-theory, homological-algebra

I've run into a curious situation in my research that is fairly elementary, but I haven't been able to find a proof or counterexample for it. I have a slight feeling that the question is false in general, but haven't been able to find an explicit counterexample.

---

Let $G$ be a finite group and $k$ a field of characteristic dividing the order of $G$. Suppose $M$ is a $kG$-module with internal direct sum decomposition $M = M_1 \oplus M_2$, and $N \subseteq M$ is a submodule of $M$ such that $M_1 \cap N = \{0\}$. Does there exist some $M_3 \supseteq N$ for which $M = M_1 \oplus M_3$?

---

The setup which leads to this question for meis as follows: I have two $kG$-modules, $A,B$ both mapping into a third $kG$-module $C$. Call the maps $f: A\to C$ and $g: A \to C$. I have that $f$ splits, that is, there exists some homomorphism $s: C \to A$ such that $f\circ s \circ f = f$. I have that $\text{im } f \cap \text{im } g = \{0\}$, and would like to show that the decomposition $C = \text{im } f \oplus \ker f\circ s$ can be modified, by changing $\ker f\circ s$ to some other submodule of $C$ containing $\text{im } g$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is false, take $M$ to be a sum of the trivial and regular $C_2=\langle \sigma\rangle$ modules over a field with two elements. So we can describe this with basis $e,f_1,f_2$ with $\sigma f_1=f_1$, $\sigma f_2=f_1+f_2$, and $\sigma e=e$.

Then look at $M_1=\{0,e\}$, $N=\{0,e+f_1\}$. The proper sub modules containing $N$ are the proper sub modules of $M/N$, which is the regular representation of $C_2$, so there is a unique proper sub module of $M$ containing $N$, and we can easily see that this is just the span of $e$ and $f_1$.

Thus, the unique sub module containing $N$ is not a valid complement for $M_1$, giving the desired counterexample.

Comment: Very nice! I was wondering if I should add the stipulation that $k$ is large enough for $G$, but I think the same construction works.